# Wordpress: custom field display twice

Tags: custom-field, ajax

I have a little bug on my WordPress...

When I added a custom field, I have no ajax, I need to saved the draft or publish to see the update.

And after I saved my post, the custom field display twice.

```
name :   Steffi

name :   Steffi
```

Help, please ! Thanks

**Update :** 
*Console with Firebug*

```
_ajax_nonce 0
_ajax_nonce-add-meta    53208ba18d
action  add-meta
metakeyinput    
metakeyselect   titre
metavalue   e
post_id 1151
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to display data?

Comment: I don't use code. I just add my custom field in my post :)
The custom field display twice in the post (admin)

Comment: Custom fields do not "display" just. That needs some code, and that's the part Steven was asking for. By default, custom fields are not displayed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys, I found **THE** solution.

Problems :

- Custom field display twice.
- No Ajax/jQuery visual feedback.

If you've been working on the file `function.php`, make sure you remove extra line breaks.

Particularly at the top and `the bottom of your file`...
If you have some line breaks, your xml got an error : 
`XML or text declaration not at start of entity`

Comment: You can prevent many problems by [not putting the ending `?>` in your `functions.php`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5764/very-new-to-coding-keep-breaking-site-trying-to-add-to-functions-php/5770#5770). Could you accept this answer (by clicking the checkbox) so the system knows you solved it? Thanks, and welcome to the WordPress Stack Exchange!

Comment: Please accept your own answer as "answer" so that this question is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add this to your config.php file:

define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );

above the line /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

[Found here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-ajax-not-working?replies=4).

Comment: config.php or wp_config.php ?

Comment: config.php doesnt exists, it's wp-config.php

Comment: it doesn't work... I don't know why. When I added the custom field: No ajax. And when I refresh, it always displays twice...

Comment: Any error message in the administration? Is it local or online? First time it's doing that?

Comment: No error message in the administration. 
It's online.
I think it's doing that since I installed WP-PostViews... (but I can't deleted it, I need it. lol)

Comment: Try to desactivate it, just to see.

Comment: When I desactivate it, no changes. I think I need to deleted ALL the files and data in database lol... Really sucks..

Update: Look my update. Ajax added the custom field, but don't udpate the post when I "clicked" on add

Comment: Doesnt update the post no when u click on 'add' cos it's ajax pozered, however if you add a custom field and get out of the post it'll be saved anyway. Cant help with the firebug infos, i personally dont know anything about that.

Comment: @Kevin : Found it !

Comment: What was the pb?

Comment: Line breaks in `functions.php`

Answer (score 0):

"Particularly at the top and the bottom of your file... If you have some line breaks, your xml got an error : XML or text declaration not at start of entity"

In addition, you should remove intermediate occurrences of php's closing tag ?>.

For example:

```
    <?php

  ...code...

    ?> 


 ...Some HTML Code...    

<?php

...code...
```